# Clicking a button in an activity opens up two activities simultaneously

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

Here I have three `activities` where one of them is a `login activity`. Whenever I click the `login button` two activities show up simultaneously. The other two `activities` are : `VendorAccount.java` and `Promotion.java`. The code is given below :

Here I have used an `intent` that whenever the task of `logging in` successfull it will start `Promotion.class`.

**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Login";
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private Button loginButton,signupButton;
EditText eml,pass;
String email,password;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    loginButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    signupButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.newuser);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            eml=findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
            pass=findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

            email=eml.getText().toString();
            password=pass.getText().toString();

           // startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Promotion.class));
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Promotion.class));
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                //updateUI(user);
                            } else {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //updateUI(null);
                            }

                            // ...
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Signup.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    //updateUI(currentUser);
}
}
```

Now when I click the `signin` button it should open `Promotion.class` which it does but with that `VendorAccount.class` is also opened.

**Promotion.java**

```
public class Promotion extends AppCompatActivity {

private BottomBar bottomBar;
private Button coupons,scanqr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.promotion);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Promotion called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    coupons=(Button)findViewById(R.id.coupons);
    scanqr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scanqr);

    bottomBar=BottomBar.attach(this,savedInstanceState);
    bottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombars_menu);
    bottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId==R.id.tab_account){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Accounts",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Promotion.this,VendorAccount.class));
            } else if (menuItemId==R.id.tab_details){
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Customer Details",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowCustomer.class));
            } else if (menuItemId==R.id.tab_coupons) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Coupons",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(Promotion.this,ShowCoupons.class));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(int menuItemId) {

        }
    });

    // Setting colors for different tabs when there's more than three of them.
    // You can set colors for tabs in three different ways as shown below.
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, 0xFF5D4037);
    bottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#7B1FA2");

    coupons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Promotion.this,Coupons.class));
        }
    });

    scanqr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"QR scan",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            configure_button();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
    // lose the current tab on orientation change.
    bottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void configure_button() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}
                    , 0);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
        startActivity(new Intent(Promotion.this,QRScan.class));
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == 0){
        if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    configure_button();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Promotion.this,QRScan.class));
                }
            }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Access Denied ! Plesae Choose Camera Access Manually ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Promotion.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("System Message!!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Hey There,!!"+"\n"+"Do Tou Really Want to Leave?");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

**VendorAccount.java**

```
public class VendorAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView displayPic;
private EditText name,addr1,addr2,phno;
private Button save;
private Button image1,image2,image3,image4;
String vendorname,vendoraddr1,vendoraddr2,vendorphno;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vendor_account);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "VendorAccount called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    displayPic=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.displaypicture);
    image1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    image3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    image4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.image4);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vendorname);
    addr1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vendoradd1);
    addr2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vendoradd2);
    phno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.vendorphno);

    displayPic.setOnClickListener(choosePic);
    image1.setOnClickListener(choosePic);
    image2.setOnClickListener(choosePic);
    image3.setOnClickListener(choosePic);
    image4.setOnClickListener(choosePic);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved in database",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            vendorname=name.getText().toString();
            vendoraddr1=addr1.getText().toString();
            vendoraddr2=addr2.getText().toString();
            vendorphno=phno.getText().toString();
        }
    });
}

public View.OnClickListener choosePic=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        final int ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE = 1234;
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
};

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1234:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            }
        }
}
}
```

As you can see I have put `Toast` messages in the `onCreate` method of every class so that I know which `class` is called. So when I click the `signin` button the `Toast` message of `Promotion.java` is displayed and then the `Toast` message of `VendorAccount.java` and the layout of `VendorAccount.java` is displayed first.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

The `manifest` and the `activiy_login` file are below :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vendorapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Coupons"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Promotion"
        android:label="Promotion"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="Login"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Signup"
        android:label="SignUp"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CouponsNew"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".QRScan"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" />
    <activity android:name=".ShowCoupons"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".qrinfo"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowCustomer"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".VendorAccount"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar">

    </activity>
</application>
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff0000"
tools:context="com.example.vendorapp.Login">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_24dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingEnd="10sp"
            android:paddingStart="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:drawablePadding="10sp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_white_24dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingEnd="10sp"
            android:paddingStart="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonPanel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="Login"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newuser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="New User? Register Here."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="30sp"
    android:layout_height="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: Can you also post your Manifest and the activity_login.xml file?

Comment: @LeoNeo, I have added them

Comment: You're using an external library for bottom bar (my guess is this one https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar )? Anyways if so, the library is deprecated which might cause compatibility issues(such as the one mentioned in answers). My suggestion would be to use this instead https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

Answer (score 1):

Your `onMenuTabSelected` gets triggered while you are initializing the `Promotiion.class` during onCreate.

Try setting a int variable to overread the first `onMenuTabSelected`.

```
public class Promotion extends AppCompatActivity {
private int itemSelectedCounter; 
bottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuTabSelected(int menuItemId) {
       if(++itemSelectedCounter > 1) {
          // your onMenuTabSelectedCode
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the BottomBar library by roughike? `setOnMenuTabClickListener()` is a method from version `1.3.9` but the latest release is `2.3.1`. The API has changed a lot. I'm wondering if there was a bug with that version that caused `setOnMenuTabClickListener()` to be called on the initial setup (the first tab is selected by default correct?) That would explain why as soon as `Promotion` launches, it immediately launches `VendorAccount`. Try upgrading to `2.3.1`, docs are [here](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)